# UI Testing and Code Coverage

Tags: testing, selenium

My company wants me to write UI tests that test the business logic (all of the use cases MUST be independently testable) I decided to do it in selenium. I have managed to create a decent product (as of now about 80% of use cases are covered, I have a video recording feature of the test run and a screenshot feature for each failing test case  -- and all of these features are accessible though an easy to use GUI). Oh, and I forgot to mention that it will work on windows 10 as well as Ubuntu (the latest LTS) and it also allows you to run the tests in a variety of browsers, which can be selected from a drop down menu in the GUI.

But my company is not happy because I have only done 80% coverage. They think I am an idiot who is progressing too slowly. They don't understand how much work was involved in creating what I have so far and how stupid it is to test business logic through the UI.

Am i being unreasonable or are they?

Comment: It is impossible for us to tell who is being unreasonable here. It is equally possible that both or neither of you are being unreasonable and it all depends on the details of what you have done and what you were asked to do. In any case, we are not going to play arbiter here.

Comment: Only you and your guts know if you are doing your best. If you feel you have done this inappropriately, or overengineered that (ie "loosing" time) then at least defend what is working. Nevertheless setting up proper testing is expensive and you should make them aware of that fact.

Comment: You managed to get 80% code coverage through the UI?! That's actually fairly amazing. I read once that testing through the UI usually garners about 20-30% code coverage.

Answer (score 2):

About your 80%. I assume it is about code coverage, right? The question is also can you test all business logic through the UI? Is every code path really available through UI actions? There might be logical path that are not executed at all. So maybe 80% is close to the maximum possible?

And normally unit tests are used to test business logic I think.

Comment: Yeah 80% code coverage is very good